# Monitors won't come back from sleep

Tags: video, graphics-card, sleep

I recently put together a computer with three [Dell S2716DG monitors](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/product/BcTrxr/dell-monitor-s2716dg) powered by a [EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 FTW Hybrid Gaming video card](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/product/z7RFf7/evga-geforce-gtx-1080-8gb-ftw-hybrid-gaming-video-card-08g-p4-6288-kr). The computer is running Windows 10 Pro. When I don't use it for a while, the monitors go to sleep and when I come back and touch a key on my keyboard or move the mouse, the monitors don't wake up. If I turn them off and on again or I press the menu button, they wake up and everything starts to work normally.

Any ideas what's going on and or how to fix it?

Comment: do you have a different monitor to test it on? Or a different computer to test with the montiors? (this will help determine if it's the computer or the monitors)

Comment: @blaine: nothing straightforward to be honest but I can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable *Monitor Deep Sleep* in monitor's OSD Menu → Others.

Comment: Wow. Why would they ship them like this. Thank you so much for the answer.